# Remove radio button text only with CSS

Tags: html, css

If I have radio button followed with text without any class/id, is there any way to remove the text? For Example if I have these code

```
<label class="radio-wrapper">
<input type="radio" id="sex_0" name="sex" value="Male"> Male
</label>
```

How to hide the text `Male` so it only show the radio button only use CSS? I've tried this so far:

```
input[type="radio"]+label { 
    display:none !important;
}
```

But still the text still coming. Also, I can't give any  or  for those text because I only have access for CSS.

Comment: `input[type="radio"]+label` wouldn't work as it selects the label element that immediately follows a radio button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `font-size` to **zero**.

```css
label.radio-wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-wrapper">
<input type="radio" id="sex_0" name="sex" value="Male"> Male
</label>
```